# why should we have import export in ecmascript when including scripts in the right order works

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecma

This could be a very fundamental question, When script include in the right order works well for functions

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ecmascript </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ECMA Script</h1>
    <script  src="piece.js"></script>
    <script  src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### piece.js

```
// function to 
function sayHello(){
    window.alert('Hello alert');
    console.log('Hello');
}

class Rectangle {

    constructor( height, width ){
        this.height = height;
        this.width  = width;
    }

    draw(){
        console.log( 'Rectangle is drawn ... height : ' + this.height + ' width :' + this.width );
    }
}
```

### app.js

```
//function invocation
sayHello();

// Object creation
rect1 = new Rectangle( 10, 4);
rect1.draw();
```

The entire code is so obvious, and it works, I have tested. Now the question is why should we have a mechanism like import, export in ecma script.

Answer (score 0):

Using modules allows you to **constrain the scope** of the variables in your script.

Imagine you had a large page with lots of different parts - you might have 10 or 20 different scripts. Without modules, each variable declared at the top level in each different script would be global. For example, your `sayHello` and `Rectangle` are both global. The more scripts and code one has, the more chance there is for such global variables to accidentally collide (for example, maybe you define a function named `handleClick` in one script, and another function also named `handleClick` in a different script). There would be problems.

Using imports instead not only removes the problem with globals (since module variables are scoped *only to their module*), but it also makes the dependency chain *explicit*, which is very useful. For example, you can see that script A depends on function `fn` from script B. (Otherwise, all you might be able to see at a glance is that script A depends on some function `fn` which is presumably defined *somewhere* in your codebase.)

Explicit imports and exports also permit tree-shaking (automatic removal of unused variables) in build systems.

Using modules can arguably make larger codebases significantly more maintainable.

But, in such a small page like in your example, you're right - one could well conclude that it *doesn't* provide any real benefit when there are only a handful of lines of code.